# JSON response returns undefined

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

First use 'json_decode' to convert array to JSON response

```
$test = [ "connections" => [ [  "title" => "Connection 1", "date"  => "01-26-2010", "id" => "1" ] ] ];

echo json_encode( $test );
```

and then process the JSON response in the front-end side.

```
$.get( 'http://cnbusiness.nextdayhost.com/ajax/get_business_connections', function(e){
   console.log( e.connections );
});
```

but unfortunately it returns 'undefined'

[image]

A view of the response using a JSON editor

[image]

I can do this

```
$.get( 'http://cnbusiness.nextdayhost.com/ajax/get_business_connections', function(e){
  $.each(JSON.parse(e),function(i,e){
    $.each(e,function(i,e){
        console.log(e.title);
    });
  });
});
```

which surely returns the data that I want but I prefer not to do a second loop.

any idea, help please?

Comment: What is the response for this particular request, you can see this in network tab

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid see my updated post.

Comment: It returning {"connections":[{"title":"Connection 1","date":"01-26-2010","id":"1"}]}, how you can say JSON response in undefined?

Comment: You may need to wait for the response before you can access the data.

Comment: I guess you just need to parse the output as json only `var some = JSON.parse(e)` and then you have json object in `some` variable

Comment: You can try to test it by running this part of the code from the above "$.get( 'http://cnbusiness.nextdayhost.com/ajax/get_business_connections', function(e){" unto your console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I'm sure you have no `header('Content-type:application/json')` in you `PHP` if I'm not mistaken. If you don't have, It will return as a `string`. You need to parse it by using `$.parseJSON` of `jQuery` built in `method`

```
$.get('http://cnbusiness.nextdayhost.com/ajax/get_business_connections', function(e) {
  $.each($.parseJSON(e),function(i,e){
    // code here ...
  });
});
```

Comment: tried but it gives me this error "VM979:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1"

Comment: thanks, you're right, all i need is set the header to "header('Content-type:application/json')"

Comment: @JuliverGalleto I'm so glad I helped you

Answer (score -1):

parse output to json, plus, because e.connection was an array,
[image]

if you want to get title from connection you can do like

```
e = JSON.parse(e)
console.log(e.connections[0].title)
```

Comment: tried that but it gives me an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"